# How to find services failed or missing dependencies in JBOSS

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to deploy an ear in the JBOSS EAP 6.3. I am getting the following error in server.log

ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started (with errors) in 76266ms - Started 1851 of 1912 services (24 services failed or missing dependencies, 494 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

My question is how will I find the 24 service which are failed or  missing dependencies.

FYI there are no more error details in the server.log

Please help me on this

Comment: On your server.log file you should find the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your comments alphamikevictor  but I could not find any error details in the server log. Do I have to make any log configuration in standalone.xml to get the deployment error logs.

Comment: Normally it will print errors on server.log. Unless it was changed or any application deployed _overrides_ your logging configuration.